# Check the time difference between the current time and the next 5th minute

Tags: python, loops, datetime

### Edited (To clarify my purpose)

I need to write a function that divides an hour into 12 intervals, finds which interval the current time lies into, and then calculates the time difference between the current time and the larger interval boundary, e.g. 0th minute, 5th minute, 10th minute, etc...

### Examples

the current time is 15:28:07, the larger interval boundary is 15:30:00

the current time is 03:00:00, the larger interval boundary is 03:05:00

the current time is 23:59:59, the larger interval boundary is 00:00:00

### What I Have Tried

I have looked through a bunch of posts but almost all of them have users pre-define the time. Here is the draft that I have:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
currentMin = now.minute 

# Some code to figure out what the larger interval boundary is
boundary = ?

target = datetime(now.year,now.month,now.date,now.hour,boundary)
duration = target-now
sleepTime = round(duration.total_seconds(),2)
time.sleep(sleepTime)

# Some other code
```

In order to find the next 5th minute, I have a list of all the boundaries and I plan to run loops to see which interval `currentMin` falls into and then assign the larger value of the interval to  `boundary`

```py
interval = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60]
```

### Problems

1st is efficiency, each iteration grabs two numbers from the list and compares with `currentMin`, but my entire program is very time-sensitive.

2nd is extreme cases, I need to take care of cases where `55 < currentMin < 60`, and where the next 5th min is the next day (The last case in the examples).

Is there a better way/simple way to achieve this? Is there a built-in command that helps you to find such a time marker easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the number of seconds since Epoch, as returned by `time.time()`, to efficiently obtain the timestamp of the next 5-minute mark with the following modulo-based calculation:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = time.time()
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp + 300 - timestamp % 300))
```

Sample output:

```
2019-08-28 16:38:57.435255
2019-08-28 16:40:00
```

Comment: This works perfectly for any cases! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only interested in finding the time needed to sleep, this should work:

```
...
seconds = -(now.minute * 60 + now.second) % 300
sleep(seconds)
```

If you also want to find the `target`, you can use

```
target = now + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
```

Comment: This method is quick and simple but when the time is at 12:00 for example, the sleep time will be 0s instead of 300s. I can just add an if statement to make sleep time equal to 300s in that case. However, for my program, I think sleep 0s works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: The time is already a multiple of 5 minutes if it is 12:00:00. Why would you wait for another 5 mins?

Comment: I am implementing a program that needs this kinda mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You can work with a `timedelta` of 5 minutes to calculate 5 minutes in the future. This will consider any hour or day changes. Then round back to the last 5 minutes.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
# go 5 minutes into the future
later5min = now + timedelta(0,0,0,0,5)
# round to 5 minutes
next5min = datetime(later5min.year, later5min.month, later5min.day, later5min.hour, 5*int(later5min.minute/5), 0, 0)
print(now)
print(next5min)
```

For sleeping, use

```
sleep((next5min-now).total_seconds())
```

This will sleep including fractions of a second.

> "entire program is very time-sensitive"

Note that on Windows, the process scheduling happens only every 17 milliseconds, so your program will never be more precise than that. I can't judge for Linux.

Comment: I am running Linux and I have read some posts saying that Linus ticks closer to 1ms but still largely depends on other programs you are running at the time. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

Based on your example is appears that the actual date/time is not important, just how many more seconds until the next 5th minute. In this case you could try something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
current_min = now.minute
current_seconds = now.second

# get how many minutes past the previous 5th minute using modulus division
# eg if currentMin is 36, 36 % 5 = 1
time_past_previous_5_min = current_min % 5

# calculate how many minutes to the next 5th minute
next_5th_min = 5 - time_past_previous_5_min

# convert to seconds
seconds = next_5th_min * 60 - current_seconds

# sleep
time.sleep(seconds)
```

Comment: Like that, you're sleeping full minutes only. It will not sleep the seconds until hh:mm:00.

Comment: Updated to handle seconds