# run python program every 15 minutes when seconds are 0

Tags: python, time, python-datetime

I have been writing this code and the time taken for the execution is about 3-4 seconds and I want it to run every 15 minutes I have been using this code

```
while True:
  if datetime.datetime.now().minute % 15 == 0:
  ...
  time.sleep(60)
```

now I cannot start the code to run exactly when the seconds on the clock are at 0 so I want the code to run exactly when the seconds are zero.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Also [Run function at a specific time in python](/q/50121539/), [How to run a python script at a specific time](/q/5677853/)

Comment: what you could do is ```now=datetime.datetime.now()```. Then you could do ```current_time = now.strftime("%S")``` to get the seconds. And then check ```if current_time=='00'``` and then ```time.sleep(900)``` for 15 minutes

Comment: There are quit a few other Q&A's if you search with `python start function every 15 minutes`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57701095/480982

Answer (score 0):

If you'll think about it - you're suspending your code for 60 seconds on `time.sleep(60)` but you're not considering the time it takes for the code to execute each time, which creates a time difference.

You could calculate the difference in time for the next execution to happen instead of constant `60`

BTW, If you want to execute a code repeatedly you could use `crontab` to execute your scripts for you, it's simple and on-time so you won't need to worry about timings